# Get Vuforia AR Camera Compass Direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Am trying to figure out how to get Vuforia AR camera compass direction, i.e. North/South/East/West. Can someone guide me on the same?

Tried to use below, but CameraDevice.Instance does not have any attribute to get compass direction.

Tried below, from a different Vuforia post, to see what attributes but this does not have any as well.

```
// Get the fields
IEnumerable cameraFields = CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraFields();

// Print fields to device logs    
foreach (CameraDevice.CameraField field in cameraFields) {    
   Debug.Log("Key: " + field.Key + "; Type: " + field.Type);    
}
```

Tried something like below.

```
GameObject cam;
cam = GameObject.Find("ARCamera");
```

and tried to print `cam.transform.forward`, but it gives me something like (0.0,0.0,1.0). If this is the right approach, can you help me understand how to get the direction from this?

Update:
I had tried a solution using Vector3.forward, right etc. But it always prints North as the direction, irrespective of the direction in which am holding my phone. Can you pls guide me on what is wrong here? I need to find the direction in which the user is holding his phone, to show some points of interest in that direction.

I attachd this script to the ARCamera (vuforia) object itself and added the statements in the start method of the script. I tried placing them in update method also, but still the same behavior.

Pls let me know if you need more details.

```
GameObject cam; 
cam = GameObject.Find ("ARCamera"); 
var dir = cam.transform.forward; 
dir.y = 0; 
dir.Normalize (); 
if (Vector3.Angle(dir, Vector3.forward) <= 45.0) { 
    Debug.Log("In Start method.. North"); 
} else if (Vector3.Angle(dir, Vector3.right) <= 45.0) { 
    Debug.Log("In Start method.. East"); 
} else if (Vector3.Angle(dir, Vector3.back) <= 45.0) { 
    Debug.Log("In Start method.. South"); 
} else { 
    Debug.Log("In Start method.. West"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Unity has something called 'Input.compass'.. so, if I set 'Input.compass.enabled=true, before starting to track location and use Input.compass.trueHeading, it gives me the direction (in terms of eulerangle, I believe) of the phone camera.. found from another blog post - https://blog.falafel.com/displaying-device-compass-unity/

Comment: It's a dead link can you repost the answer here pls ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve an **In Game Compass** you could buy one from the `AssetStore` [here](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/page=1/sortby=relevance/query=compass).
 But If you want to make it yourself for free you can start [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/756125/compass-bar-gui-help.html) with a pretty basic one

**EDIT1**

Here is a script that could help

```
GameObject cam; 
cam = GameObject.Find ("ARCamera"); 

    if (cam.transform.eulerAngles.y >= 0 && cam.transform.eulerAngles.y <= 90)
    {
        print("Looking at NORTH");
    }
    else if (cam.transform.eulerAngles.y >= 91 && cam.transform.eulerAngles.y <= 180)
    {
        print("Looking at EAST");
    }
    else if (cam.transform.eulerAngles.y >= 181 && cam.transform.eulerAngles.y <= 270)
    {
        print("Looking at SOUTH");
    }
    else if (cam.transform.eulerAngles.y >= 271 && cam.transform.eulerAngles.y <= 360)
    {
        print("Looking at WEST");
    }   
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I just want to know the direction in which user is pointing his camera to, via the script. I do not want to create a Game Compass. I just want to show some points of interest in the direction, in which user is pointing his camera to. so I need to know the direction for the same.

Comment: That is totally different than what you have asked. Still my second suggestion would help you out, if you take a look at it.

Comment: Yes. I had tried a solution similar to what was mentioned in suggestion 2, using Vector3.forward, right etc.              GameObject cam; cam = GameObject.Find (“ARCamera");
var dir = cam.transform.forward;    dir.y = 0;   dir.Normalize ();    if (Vector3.Angle(dir, Vector3.forward) <= 45.0) {    Debug.Log("In Start method.. North");   }  else if (Vector3.Angle(dir, Vector3.right) <= 45.0) {    Debug.Log("In Start method.. East");   }  else if (Vector3.Angle(dir, Vector3.back) <= 45.0) {    Debug.Log("In Start method.. South");   }  else {    Debug.Log("In Start method.. West");   }

Comment: but it prints out North always, irrespective of the direction in which I point my phone. Can you pls guide me what am I doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it possible to update your question with the script that you have tried and please mention where you attached it and what the error is, thanks

Comment: I just updated the question with the details. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @csharpnewbie Edited my answer.

Comment: thanks. I tried this solution, but cam.transform.eulerAngles.y always comes as 0. I put this script in Start as well as Update methods of the script attached to the ARCamera. I tried moving to different directions, but cam.transform.eulerAngles.y is always 0, hence direction comes as North always. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use `public GameObject cam` and when you attach the script make sure you are passing the correct camera to the script. If that does not work please debug your code and see if cam is ever assigned. Sidenote: code has been tested on my Unity project, works like a charm!

Comment: I changed GameObject to public and associated it to my cam and the script is associated as Init script to my ARCamera too. But still  cam.transform.eulerAngles.y is always 0, hence direction comes as North always. Is there a way that you could share your sample project, so that I can check it? Am new to unity, and am testing on a iPhone, after building the project from Unity. So am not sure how to debug. I will check it out too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142943/discussion-between-hristo-and-csharpnewbie).

Comment: looks like Unity has something called 'Input.compass'.. so, if I set 'Input.compass.enabled=true, before starting to track location and use Input.compass.trueHeading, it gives me the direction (in terms of eulersangle, I believe) of the phone camera.. found from another blog post. thanks for your help.